# Is there a way to GroupBy into groups of one?

Tags: c#

I've developed myself into a corner, counting on a function only needing to process grouped records. Now it's being tasked to process individual records. I don't want to go about refactoring my code significantly just to handle processing records individually. Is there a way to make a C# List group each record on its own using .GroupBy?

```
List<string[]> CsvData = new List<string[]>() { };
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string[]>> GroupedCsvData = CsvData.GroupBy(x => x);
```

This yields an error of: "Cannot implicitly convert type `'IEnumerable<IGrouping<string[], string[]>>'` to `'IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string[]>>'`. An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?"

Comment: I feel like an absolute imbecile for having to ask this question. It feels like it deserves a "no duh" type of answer, but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Is GroupBy(x => x) insufficient?

Comment: Ahh - that's perhaps part of the rub, that it's a complex object. Allow me to edit.

Comment: `Select` has an overload that includes the index (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__). Use it, then `GroupBy` the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you had the potential for duplicates, you could do something like:

```
var items = new List<string>();
var groups = items.Select((item, index) => new {
    Item = item,
    Index = index
}).GroupBy(o => o.Index, o => o.Item);
```

Comment: Will need to select out just the Item after Grouping.

Comment: Yeah, there is an `elementSelector`. With the update, the return type is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, string>>`

Comment: So, what adjustments would need to be made to change the results to IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string[]>>? I bet this could be faster than generating a new, completely wasted Guid with every record

Comment: This isn't generating a `Guid` @baker.nole. What makes you think it is? This answer is basically the same as @Enigmativity's answer (except his has the `ToString` which might be useful if you specifically want to group by `string`).

Comment: @mjwills - regarding Guids, I was referring to a comment I made under user2864740's suggestion. It got the job done, but I prefer solutions akin to this and Enigmativity as it further guarantees uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that generating unique `string` key per element is the way to go. Try this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string[]>> GroupedCsvData =
    CsvData
        .Select((Csv, Index) => new { Csv, Key = Index.ToString() })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Csv);
```

Comment: This looks even better than a Guid as a guarantee against possible accidental grouping, as there would be no way to accidentally group on an index. I'll be testing this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may 'close to' the desired intent:

```
// List<string[]> -> IEnumerable<string> -> IGrouping<string, string>
CsvData.SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(x => x);
```

CsvData is a List so in CsvData.GroupBy(x => x), x (the Key) is a string[] and not a string.

Comment: That is close indeed. Had you also suggested the "new object()" code?

Comment: @baker.nole I did, but that did not 'honor' the posted key type. I guess: "I'm not entirely 100% sure what the desired output of the request is."

Comment: The desired output is a IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string[]>> - and that suggestion rang a bell with me when I saw it. Instead of "new object()" I'm using "Guid.NewGuid().ToString()" and testing